# expresscart install error npm ERR! Failed at the fibers@2.0.0 install script

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to install expressCart on my local machine

But it throws the following error:

> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! fibers@2.0.0
>   install: `node build.js || nodejs build.js` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm
>   ERR!  npm ERR! Failed at the fibers@2.0.0 install script. npm ERR!
>   This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional
>   logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   /home/sugumar/.npm/_logs/2019-05-29T08_06_20_254Z-debug.log

my node version is v12.3.1

my npm version 6.9.0

Answer (score 0):

Try the latest [version](https://github.com/mrvautin/expressCart). I've installed running the same version as you and its working fine.